# Difference between .pb and .pbtxt in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, protocol-buffers

When saving a graph in tensorflow

```
tf.train.write_graph(
    graph_or_graph_def,
    logdir,
    name,
    as_text=True
)
```

There is this flag:
`as_text`: If `True`, writes the graph as an ASCII proto.

I found out that if it is `False` it saves the graph as a binary proto.

> - My question is what is the difference between those two protos?
> - And why is there a difference?
> - Do they have advantages over another?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#text_or_binary

Comment: exactly what I was looking for (Y) - I cast this into an answer for better readability.

Comment: I believe the above link changed to https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.10/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/tool_developers/index.md since the original page seems to have been updated

Comment: thanks I added your link to the answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Thanks to a comment this question can be answered (text is from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.10/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/tool_developers/index.md))

**Text or Binary?**

There are actually two different formats that a ProtoBuf can be saved in.

- **TextFormat**

  is a human-readable form, which makes it nice for **debugging** and **editing**, but can get large when there's numerical data like weights stored in it. You can see a small example of that in graph_run_run2.pbtxt.
- **Binary Format**

  files are **a lot smaller** than their text equivalents, even though they're not as readable for us. In this script, we ask the user to supply a flag indicating whether the input file is binary or text, so we know the right function to call. You can find an example of a large binary file inside the inception_v3 archive, as inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb.